# How to deal with defamations perpetrated through public chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, moderators, chat

I must premise that the present OP, albeit motivated by a personal experience on Mathematical Stack Exchange, aims to solicit an open discussion about an important general issue concerning the common rules for a fair behavior in formulating comments on public chat rooms here on the Stack Exchange network.

For that reason, please do not focalize on the specific cases I'm referring to, but consider those just as a concrete example to better guide the discussion about the main questions.

Recently I have been suspended for 7 days for a comment in which I've expressed my own opinion about the lack in correctness and honesty by one user in his/her action on MSE. That comment has been considered rude and not tolerable by MSE Moderation Team, leading to my first suspension in 5 months of experience here.

Here below the message I've received on April 22 at UTC 6.18 PM from MSE Moderation Team to notify the suspension.

[image]

I fully respect the decision made by MSE Moderation Team, indeed my comment was of course out of place and eligible for some punitive/corrective action by the MSE Moderation Team.

What I can't really understand is why the same criteria for the suspension were not applied to a deliberate defamation action against my person perpetrated by some users and posted on public chat rooms named CRUDE and Math Mods Office which, I presume, are not aimed to manipulate someone else's reputation.

I’m referring notably to the following deliberate and reiterate public false accusations:

1. First remarkable defamation on March 15 2018 at UTC 2.00 PM on Math
   Mods Office chat room

   [image]
2. Second remarkable defamation on April 21 2018 at UTC 6.17 PM and
   8.11 PM on CRUDE chat room

   [image]
3. Third remarkable defamation on April 22 2018 at UTC 6.17 PM and 4.06
   PM on Math Mods Office chat room (2 hours before suspension decision)

   [image]

Notably my questions are:

1. Why a rude but extemporaneous opinion given during an open debate by
   a comment can lead to a 7 days suspension while a purposeful,
   deliberate and reiterate public senseless accusations (i.e.
   defamation), perpetrated through public chat rooms, which should be
   aimed to different scopes, can be tolerated and allowed by the
   community?
2. Is that abusive use of the chat rooms compatible with the fair harmony of the
   community?
3. Am I overestimating that issue?

I've formulated almost the same questions to the MSE Moderation Team after my suspension, but up to now I didn't receive any reply about that.

With reference to the abusive use of chat room, I’ve received the following reply from SE support.

> Stack Overflow Team (Stack Overflow)
>
> Apr 23, 10:45 EDT
>
> Hello,
>
> This kind of behavior is not forbidden in a general sense, but it has resulted in problematic behavior in the past. Ultimately, it just requires keeping a close eye. Most of these groups across our network operate in a way where they only target clearly bad questions or answers, staying away from more subjective materials. If a group ever becomes abusive and starts closing clearly good questions or doing other things that become problematic to the site, the moderators can always step in and intervene.
>
> Regards,
>
> Stack Overflow Team

Please feel free to express your opinions and suggestions in the most open and frank way.

Thanks!

Gimusi

Comment: Public speculation that you're breaking the voting rules is not rude, per se, nor is it a direct insult. And it certainly isn't defamatory. Your recourse is to flag the content you don't like, or to contact SE if you think the moderators' actions aren't enough. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @T.Bongers Why is it not equivalent to an accuse of lack in "correctness and honesty"? Please explain what is the difference? Please also avoid targeted downvoting and deleting for a while, at least here on Meta.

Comment: As you already did post about this to the main meta. It could make sense to include [a link to that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309609/).

Comment: @quid Yes indeed at first posted the OP there and I've received many good suggestions to improve the OP in order to make it more neutral and less personal as possible. Since you are a moderator on MSE, I really would appreciate your point of view on my questions. Thanks!

Comment: Related: Some discussion about targeting specific users (in general) was recently discussed in CRUDE [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2018/4/25)

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks John for pointing out this thread, it is really an important issue in my opinion. My point here is more specific. If I have a certain bad opinion on some user, can I freely speculate about that and express my thoughts on the public chat rooms explicitely referring to that user?

Comment: I stumbled on this particular post you mention and its comments in the midst of them happening. I was surprised to see that you were suspended for them (most of the ones which I saw were the defense of a point of view against conflicting ones). The particular comment that was mentioned in the mod message is one which I disapprove heavily and would like inexistent on this site (and should be rightly deleted), but I feel it is heavily (and I can't stress this enough) *inconsistent* for people to say that it is the kind to go "way too far to be tolerated". Worse is frequently tolerated.

Comment: I think that you may also try to talk with at least two moderators regarding this issue **privately**. I always try to do so that when I get very much confused regarding issues that I consider require moderator attention.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44100624#44100624)?

Comment: @user170039 Is your advice that the OP should confer with some mods  unbeknowst to some other mods?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Thanks for your comment but please do not focalize on the particular example I've mentioned. On the other hand, If you can point out some other different example of abusive use of chat rooms it could be useful for the discussion.

Comment: @user170039 I disapprove of that comment as well (there was some conversation about that, which can be read in the CRUDE room), but I've engaged in constructive conversation with the user that made that comment. It could be taken as an example, but there are even worse ones out there, which range from veiled toxic comments to outright rude and childish ones.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo "Worse is frequently tolerate." As I said, it is not about one comment but a pattern of behavior. The pattern being gratuitous personal attacks. The sentence itself is superficially relatively mild, in its rather formal style. This does not alter the fact that the intent of the sentence is nothing but to insult some other user. (It was not I that wrote the suspension message, but I explicitly supported the decision beforehand, as did a third of us.) Further, just that you do not see a reaction to it does not mean that something is "tolerated."

Comment: I am disturbed by the fact that someone suggested that this question should be closed (It won't, at least no right now. I voted agains it as did two other reviewers.) Why would anyone suggest that? Aren't discussions about etiquette appropriate here?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Just in case you aren't aware, some cranks (as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157250/spotting-crankery)) have fanatic supporters, who insist on ignoring even clear evidence (such as [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51337?m=41898713#41898713)) and [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48175/dictatorship-communism-or-democracy/48192#comment123608_48192) and [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/127942)). I suggest you think very carefully about the moral/ethical implications of letting cranks run wild.

Comment: relevant post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2747604/9003

Comment: @amWhy that’s not relevant at all, did you read the OP? It is about how to deal with abusive comments on public chat rooms and not about any particular OP.

Comment: "How to deal with defamations perpetrated through public chat rooms?": Ans:   One must first and foremost recognize those instances  when one is merely *perceiving* what might by or could strike one as a defamation..  And just as immediately, one refrains from accusing others of defamation when in fact observations have been well document to warrant honest, questions posted in good faith, or posting meta posts asking ***"How to deal with defamations perpetrated through public chat rooms?"*** (when in fact there are no demamations?).

Comment: @amWhy I don’t know what is your idea of defamation but since I do not have any sock-puppets account, I would suggest that this kind of accusations promoted by chat rooms shouldn’t be allowed and not tolerated  by moderators.

Comment: i support ,,,@gimusi

Comment: @lomber Thanks! They are going also to close and shut up also this small space of freedom! Your support is really appreciate ;)

Comment: That's good you don't have any, gimusi.  Calm down.  No one accused you of anything.   Please keep calm, and breath deelply.  Questions were raised, but no one claimed you did wrong.  Stay calm.  It's all good.

Comment: You began this post with your correspondence with the mod team re: your suspension.  Do not try to divert blame to others who did not accuse you of anything, but rather raised question.  That's a far cry from telling someone they lack the virtues of correctness and honesty.  Think about it, some more, @gimusi.

Comment: @amWhy as usual you are loosing the key point of the OP and trying to enter into a personal dispute. You can express your point of view on the question posed by an answer here. What do you think about the fair use of public chat rooms?

Comment: @user21820 I do not want to let cranks run wild. However, I don't want witchhunts. One thing that sets apart our society from a medieval one is the [right to a fair trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_a_fair_trial). A trial which begins with difamations and/or insults is, almost by definition, not a fair trial (I'm not referring to OP here, but to the kinds of comments I mention). Furthermore, if we treat cranks without a proper logical reasoning, justification and **impartiality**, I am afraid we are sharing some similiarities with them for the sake of the ends justifying the means.

Comment: @quid 'The pattern being gratuitous personal attacks. (...) [T]he intent of the sentence is nothing but to insult some other user.' All those characteristics fall exactly under what I mention with "worse is frequently tolerated". And I don't understand what you mean by 'just that you do not see a reaction to it does not mean that something is "tolerated".' How is it not tolerated, then?

Comment: @amWhy Please, note that I explicitly say "I'm not referring to OP here, but to the kinds of comments I mention".

Comment: Please Aloizio, you're simply trying to change the subject, off topic.  Goodbye.

Comment: This is not longer a self-contained topic/thread.  so long.

Comment: @amWhy The topic is about "defamations perpetrated through public-chat-rooms". My last comments address precisely that, and in a sense of generality as OP wants. What is off-topic?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo "How is it not tolerated, then?" So you are of the opinion that you must be informed about each and every action a moderator might take because otherwise it does not count?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: You would do better than to insinuate witchhunts. Fair trial here include being **honest**, which means calling a duck a duck, and a nut a nut, and an evil person an evil person. You yourself admitted that medical quacks cause real harm to people, but they are using the very same 'argument' that they are victims of censorship or witchhunts. Sorry, but that holds no water when the judgement is **true**.

Comment: @quid No, of course not. That is a rather extreme interpretation of my question. I asked that question because one possible interpretation of your assertion is that "no reaction exists, but we don't think it is good behaviour". If you tell me that *actions are taken*, but they can't be communicated, I perfectly understand.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo to give an example, sometimes we write mod messages without suspension; it is also not impossible that you miss the fact that a user was suspended. It is also true that we do not act on each and every transgression. Sometimes since we do not notice, yet also as a matter of efficiency. It is not clear what specific type of comments you have in mind with "way worse".  The example is actually pretty bad. It is a pure and calculated ad hominem, and was written as such. You see it here. OP systematically tries to denigrate another user. That's abusive.

Comment: @user21820 I don't believe life is so binary and deterministic like that. I also think that claiming to know assertively what a duck, nut and evil person is, and even when a judgement is **true** (this one is particularly worrisome for me), is not a good habit, and also a common trait of cranks. If the duck is a problem because it quacks, then let the reason of judgement be that it quacks. Relying on it being a duck as a justification is begging the question, and calling it a duck preemptively without a proper reasoning instills bias.

Comment: @quid Thanks for the exemplification.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: **You** are the one making a false dichotomy. Never did I say that we can always classify in a binary deterministic fashion. Some people are obviously quacks, and others are clearly not, and some others or not so clear-cut. And **you** falsely imply that I attempt to justify claims that a duck is a duck by relying on it being a duck. It is ridiculous to force everyone to justify every single statement they make, so you cannot rationally expect justification for everything. And if anyone wants my justification, they can easily request.

Comment: You are also **wrong** that we must never make any judgement call preemptively. Concerning (scientific) cranks, the general public is **often incapable** of a correct judgement if left to their own fancies. This is the same problem as (but less dangerous than) medical quacks. If you insist on letting quacks spread their nonsense to the public before you attempt to stop them, even though you have high confidence that they are quacks, **you** will be (partly) responsible for allowing harm to come to their victims, including any deaths.

Comment: Likewise, any ruling body has a reasonable responsibility to restrict the freedoms of some people in order to preserve the freedoms of more deserving people. This is why we put some people into jail for years, to **preemptively** prevent them from committing any future crimes during their jail term! Similarly, moderators ban some users to **preemptively** prevent them from causing future disturbance during their suspension period. Consistent with this, I am against punishment/restriction for its own sake. So do not associate what I do or write with anything of that sort.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for this deep and articulated discussion on general principles but I would really also appreciate an answer to the simple questions posed here. Can we use public chat rooms to formulate our accuse or suspicions on lack of correctness and honesty by other users? What your though about that precise point?

Comment: @gimusi: I read quid's answer and basically agree with it. Since you ask me for my opinion, your attitude can be vastly improved. Your comment that was the stated reason for the ban asserts not only that the other party is dishonest and cares not about correctness, but also implies that you are honest and correct. Furthermore, you call them virtues, which implies that you are morally superior. That is also an error, because correctness is **not** a virtue but a factual issue. One can be virtuous but incorrect at times. The comments you red-highlighted do not assert anything false about you.

Comment: They imply doubt about whether you use the site according to the rules, but that's it. So it is up to the moderators to affirm or deny whether the suspicions were correct. Don't forget that all these suspicions were publicly posted in the Mods Chat-room, so the moderators' responses would also be publicly available. Would you have preferred that they do it privately?

Comment: @user21820 "And you falsely imply that I attempt to justify claims that a duck is a duck by relying on it being a duck." Why call it a duck, then? Do their actions not stand by themselves for scrutiny? What is the purpose that you accomplish with that, exactly, that is not accomplished with linking the relevant posts? For instance, the OP here saying that another user was "dishonest and incorrect" is also honesty from their part. Honesty, by itself, is not so important as you imply, imho. And also degenerates quickly to rudeness.

Comment: @user21820 Also, "It is ridiculous to force everyone to justify every single statement they make". I never said that. One should not have to justify every single statement they make. But if that statement potentially hurts the integrity of some individual (or is defamatory in any other way), then, imho, **yes, you have to**. Particularly in a public environment.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: One by one... (Duck) Just like you use the word "duck" in English, so that other people know what you are talking about, I use the word "nut" or "crank", and furthermore I go to the trouble of linking posts that **explain** how to classify them in a highly objective manner. (Actions stand by themselves) Answered: "the general public is often incapable of a correct judgement if left to their own fancies". You clearly are unaware of the way cranks succeed, because of the unwillingness of experts to call them out, which makes the public uncertain and more likely to believe them.

Comment: (OP's words) **Totally not as you claimed**. Did you read what I wrote above? "Furthermore, you call them virtues, which implies that you are morally superior." (Rudeness) When you resort to calling things rude to dismiss them, your argument has become flimsy. Murderers can say you are rude and abusive for calling them a criminal and putting them into jail. (Hurt integrity) No I do not have to when **the estimated harm to others is greater**; "any ruling body has a reasonable responsibility to restrict the freedoms of some people in order to preserve the freedoms of more deserving people."

Comment: @user21820 Things are very elementary: chat rooms should be used to discuss, in a polite and balanced way, the issues which they are aimed to. What about the 2nd remarkable defamation formulated in the public chat rooms CRUDE? What it was aimed to? Isn't it a clear example of abusive use of a public chat room? As already pointed out for the others 2 defamatory claims the fact is more subjective but I think that this kind of issue should be handled with care and not as public discussion based on personal opinion of some user or restricted group of users.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo This is an interesting related post on Meta SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309645/were-more-aggressively-enforcing-self-moderation-in-chat. It seems that this kind of issue about abusive use of chat rooms is spreaded out on SE network. Maybe you could bring there to their attention some relevant example of abusive use of chat rooms which you encountered on MSE.

Comment: @user21820 Note talso that I've already recognized that the comment reported in the motivation for the suspension was badly posed and deserved some kind of corrective/punitive action. It is completely out of discussion here.

Comment: @gimusi: **Twice now**, you both seem to wish to evade my analogy; is calling a murderer a murderer defamatory? **No, if it is a fact.** Neither have you acknowledged that I have the opinions of professional mathematicians to back me up when I call a crank a crank, while you do not.

Comment: @user21820 To call a murderer a murderer publicly, you must establish that he is a murderer beyond reasonable doubt. That is my point all along. Also, the analogy is not very good, since a "murderer" is not a judgement of character and/or mental capabilities, and so can be seen as an *objective* accusation which should be properly judged, and thus neutral. Honesty, correctness etc are not so, and implying someone is defective in those regards should be carefully handled, for reasons of basic *etiquette*, among other things.

Comment: @user21820 is CRUDE chat room aimed to formulate personal suspicions about moral integrity about users? a personal suspicion reiterated over time through public chat rooms is strongly defamatory and detrimental for the reputation of the user involved. I'm of the idea that this abusive use of chat rooms should be not tolerated for the fair harmony of the community.

Comment: @user21820 To be explicit: for example, the messages which have a hidden user in the OP have justifications. They could, perhaps, be made in a more private manner, that is certainly debatable, but they are justified immediately together with the accusation, and they also pertain to an *objective* accusation without resorting to insults. That seems to be proper behaviour, in the sense I am talking about here. (However, as I said in other times, I disagree that CRUDE is the place for that, but that is another issue altogether. And 2 of the 3 messages were not on CRUDE anyway).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Look I said very clearly that I consider **gimusi**'s comment ("correctness and honesty are not among your virtues") as **unacceptable**. You are the one misreading me. Since I link to a mathematically rather clear definition of "crank", and I only make such assertions when I am **qualified** to evaluate it, you have not demonstrated any issue with **my** comment.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: So let me repeat, in case it is still not clear. I agree that "implying someone is defective in [honesty] should be carefully handled, for reasons of basic etiquette". For reasons I stated earlier, "correctness" **is not a virtue**, so it is a different matter if we want to assert that someone is incorrect. Concerning establishing objective accusations beyond reasonable doubt, you should acknowledge that I do **exactly that** before I use the term "crank" or "nut". If you take issue with that, then define "reasonable doubt". Bottom-line: you've supported my point. Thanks!

Comment: @user21820 I think that's a tangent; the usage of "correct" is just different. It was not about factually being right or wrong but about behaving in a correct (i.e., appropriate) way.

Comment: @quid: If indeed "correctness" was used to mean "decorum", I agree with you. I do not recall the original comment conveying that, but I no longer can see it in its context, so never mind.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: My last comment was to make clear that your very arguments regarding the use of "honesty and correctness" is exactly why I consider **gimusi**'s comment to be unacceptable. Your [comment here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms?noredirect=1#comment117492_28331) implied that **I** thought the comment was okay. Perhaps you thought I made such a comment. I never use insinuations. You on the contrary began insinuating a witchhunt. I strongly suggest you reflect on the way you talked to me here.

Comment: And I was not sarcastic; I was being factual.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: And for the last time, **I am not the one making or supporting comments that demean a person**. **gimusi** was the one who did that and got suspended for that. The only comment brought up here that had anything to do with me was my comment using the word "nut", and that is not a judgement of character but a judgement of content produced. You clearly do not know me at all, because I never demean cranks even if I call them out as cranks. I always consider them as capable of turning away from crankery and achieving true competency if they wish to.

Comment: @user21820 Let me observe that, as clarified here by quid, I wasn't suspended for the single comment as it seems by the notification received but "for a pattern of behavior over an extended period of time".

Comment: @gimusi: Thank you for the clarification; sorry I was imprecise.

Comment: @user21820 You are welcome, that's of course a minor issue! What I really consider critical here is the fair use of chat rooms (and comment more in general) in order to avoid actions which can be lesive for any user. This kind of suspicion from my point of view should be handled in a complete private modality.

Comment: @gimusi: I have no issue at all with people raising their suspicions privately. But you see, it is one thing to post factual observations (as long as it is not calculated manipulation), and it is quite another thing to put down others' characters. But why don't you explicitly address the comments that you red-highlighted then? If you in fact did not upvote poor questions, you should be upfront about that, since that is contrary to site quality guidelines and precisely what that user is annoyed with. Also, remember that you are not the only one with comments deleted by the moderators.

Comment: @user21820 My point is that even the factual observation, also when made in good-faith, which can be lesive of the reputation of some user, for the fair harmony of the community, should be formulated privately by means of the proper tools we have here con SE network. Once that those kind of suspicion are formulated and reiterated through public chat rooms, aimed to different scopes, they become a defamatory action even if the intent is not defamatory. I really don't see why we can't agree to use the proper tools to communicate this kind of issue to the Moderation Team.

Comment: @user21820  The discussion about OP/answer deletion is not the main point here. Anyway, I may have a different point of view from you about deletion but I fully respect your one. I can't accept when the deletion is promoted always from the same group of people for questions which are partially supported from many other users and that do not fit the criteria established for deletion (I'm talking about a small minority of cases, then I do not consider that a big issue).

Comment: @gimusi: If the moderators do not mind receiving information in a public chat-room, I really don't see why you can't be satisfied with that. You can always post an answer to your own Meta post here and see how the community views your take. Concerning bad posts please read [the FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). If users insist on answering bad questions contrary to the site guidelines, I really don't see why they can't accept that the bad questions may get cleaned up eventually. And most of them are homework questions too.

Comment: @user21820 **"If the moderators do not mind receiving information in a public chat-room"** is precisely the main point of the present OP. Also quid suggests to use no public medium but it seems a too weak position to me. For the advantage of the community, I think that this kind of use should be expressely not allowed. I see that on the latter point we have two opposite points of view. Do you think that this is the official position by the whole Moderation Team? I would really appreciate also some words on that point by some other moderators. Thanks

Comment: @user21820 For the bad questions consider that I'm here on MSE just since a few months and that I'm aquiring experience about that. At the moment I agree with you that we should not answer completely to bad questions but I'm not for suddenly closure/deletion. Maybe we could try to engage the asker in order to improve the OP and give just some hints to see his/her reaction and in order to make work the asker mainly by him/herself on the OP.

Comment: By your own view, you should complain about [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms/28332?noredirect=1#comment117553_28332) to the moderators because it baldly implies that my comment is senseless. After you do that, then we can continue. Thanks.

Comment: @user21820: How **exactly** is it true that "[this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms/28332?noredirect=1#comment117553_28332) to the moderators baldly(?) implies that [your] comment is senseless"? When did I state that explicitly? Even if it was stated explicitly, don't you think calling a really senseless comment, "senseless" appropriate?

Comment: @user170039: It is appropriate if it is senseless, but **per gimusi's criteria** (not mine) you shouldn't make such defamatory remarks. Don't get started. You're obviously trying to influence other users against me.

Comment: @user21820: Stop making baseless accusations against me. If you think that I have made any defamatory remarks, justify it. Otherwise, please stop.

Comment: Please mates try to stay into the main point of the discussion. Do we agree that it should be better maintain a polite behaviour also in the chat rooms without refer to any particular user notably when we want focus the ttention on alleged uncorrect behaviuor?

Comment: @gimusi: One should never violate the [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, in any case.

Comment: @user170039 I fully agree, it would suffice to resolve many issues here on MSE.

Comment: I'm really confident that also @user21820 can agree with this basic common rule for the community.

Comment: @gimusi: You do not know user170039's history. He/she singled out my calling out of some crank, and insinuated in comments to quid [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms?noredirect=1#comment117470_28332) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms?noredirect=1#comment117553_28332) that it is a senseless comment. Are these not as 'defamatory' than the ones in your post?

Comment: @user21820 Let try to close the past issues here and try to look for the future. My impression is that you both are very nice people, maybe there was only some misunderstanding! Do we agree on the "be nice" policy? That would be a good starting point to discuss in a more constructive way.

Answer (score 8):

You were not suspended for a single comment but for a pattern of behavior over an extended period of time.

The comments in chat are not simply an attack on you, they raise  legitimate questions based on observed facts. It is admissible, even desirable, that users that observe unusual voting patterns report them. Many cases of cheating were caught in this way. Some think it might be preferable not to raise them publicly (you can note that I suggested to inform us directly/privately), but there is also an argument to be made that it is more open (honest, if you like) to raise them publicly.

Note that the comments do not only propose sock-puppets as explanation. While you can exclude that you have sock-puppets, you cannot control and know how others vote for you. In that sense, you cannot even know if the questions are without substance.

But, as you said you were suspended for being rude and not for voting irregularities; indirectly, this supports your stance that you do not have sock-puppets.

Comment: Thank for your balanced answer. Let me observe and remark again that I'm not discussing at all about my suspension, I think that it was absolutely correct and of course I also know that I've not any sock-puppets account (that the reason why I'm using the term "defamation"). What I'm asking for is about the limits for a fair use of the chat rooms. From your answer I can argue that the public chat room CRUDE can be used also to speculate about lack in correctness and honesty by some user or group of users without run the risk to receive a suspension.

Comment: A key criterion is whether the comments seem to be made in good-faith. Nobody *asserted* that you have sock-puppets. A plausible concern about voting on and around your posts was raised. If you have a plausible concern about the integrity of some users' actions you are free to raise them. As said, some think it is better to do so non-publicly.

Comment: Let me observe that "I'm really beginning to believe that gimusi" and "take seriously our suspicion that gimusi" are really close to a fully assertion. Moreover when this kind of "plausible concerns" are made from a group of users inclined to insults and threats it is really difficult for me to consider those kind of comments to be made in good-faith. I understand your point but maybe it should be better if this kind of "plausible concern" should be handled by flagging directly to the moderators the indicted OP and using the chat rooms for their proper scope.

Comment: I do not consider this as particularly close to an assertion, e.g.,  "beginning to believe" is weaker than "believe" which is weaker than "strongly believe" which is still no assertion, but that's maybe subjective. Further, if somebody insists that moderators investigate it is a strong sign that the claim is made in good-faith. If it would be intended in bad-faith knowing it is not true there'd be no point at all to ask moderators to investigate. It only makes sense if one sincerely believes it could be true. (Regarding the appropriate choice of medium, I think I addressed this already.)

Comment: I don't see how this post answers @gimusi's question. Can you point out explicitly which parts of your post answers (or at least attempts to answer) which part of his/her question?

Comment: @user170039 Thanks for your comment, I think that the answer and the related comments by quid address the questions, even if not explicitely. It seems that this kind of use of chat rooms, out of their proper scope, even if it is not recommended, is allowed whether the comments seem to be made in good-faith by moderators.

Comment: @user170039 I tried to explain along the lines of the examples given that things that are personal attacks plain and simple are not legitimate, while comments that raise an actual concern can be legitimate even if they could also be construed as an attack. Further, there are a variety of (implicit) claims in Q1, and I thus had to address those.

Comment: You wrote, "there are a variety of (implicit) claims in Q1". What are they *exactly* and why didn't you address them in a comment?

Comment: @user170039 what is your point exactly?

Comment: As stated in my previous comment.

Comment: @user170039 the implicit claims in Q1 could be learned by reading Q1 but alright. "Why a rude but extemporaneous opinion given during an open debate by a comment can lead to a 7 days suspension" this is a claim. It happens to be false.  "while a purposeful, deliberate and reiterate public senseless accusations (i.e. defamation), perpetrated through public chat rooms," this is a claim which happens to be false. "which should be aimed to different scopes," this is a claim which is at least debatable. Once all this would be removed, nothing would remain.  Q2 and Q3 are not real questions.

Comment: @quid let me point out that the first claim for Q1 happens to be false only after your explanation given here about the motivation for the suspension. By the notifications received about suspension it seems that the suspension was just motivated by the reported comment.

Comment: @quid Let me also observe that define false the second claim of Q1 is at least a subjective matter. I could partially agree for your interpretation for the 1st and 3rd remarkable defamation made on Math Mods Office but the comment given on the chat room CRUDE is a clear example of abusive comment from my point of view.

Comment: As @gimusi has already said, I also think that the first claim is false (thanks for you explanation). Although if the suspension of OP in this case was **motivated** by it, then the policy of MSE in treating comments doesn't seem to be consistent in evaluating comments.

Comment: Regarding your alleged 'falsification' of the second claim, I think that it needs more explanation. This is so because the comment I linked [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms/28332?noredirect=1#comment117384_28331) supports the weaker claim that claim that "purposeful or deliberate or reiterate public senseless accusations perpetrated through public chat rooms" is tolerated.

Comment: Of course I admit that the standard response for Q2 is "no" and it may seem like a very trivial question, but it is not clear to me at all what you meant by it being not a "real" question. Regarding Q3, the matter is much more debatable. In fact, I think that this is one of the reasons that prompted me to discuss with mods the issues that I considered serious. So, again, it is not clear to me at all what you meant by Q3 not being a "real" question.

Comment: @user170039 I would not describe what was said as senseless. It had a specific and legitimate purpose. I am not at liberty to discuss this in all detail, but I do consider the comments, especially those mentioned in OP, as useful to me as a moderator. Whether or not the form of transmitting the information followed best practices is something that can be discussed, but the substances of the observations was useful information to have.

Comment: @quid With reference to your assertion given in the second comment **"Further, if somebody insists that moderators investigate it is a strong sign that the claim is made in good-faith"** let me observe that I can agree with that only whether the reiterated suspicion is declared in a private modality. In the case it is made more than once through public chat rooms, it can be strongly lesive of the reputation for the user involved.

Comment: @quid Moreover it is not clear to me how those kind of verifications are handled and, in particular, whether once the verification is completed, Moderation Team is going to give through the same public medium the result of the check to disprove or confirm the original suspicion.

Comment: @quid: To which comment were you referring? Are you saying that the comment I linked [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms/28332?noredirect=1#comment117384_28331) is **not** senseless?

Comment: @gimusi I already confirmed in this very post that I do not have evidence for you having sock-puppets. Thus I am at the standard hypothesis that I have for any user that is to assume there are none.

Comment: @quid Thanks, then may I ask, if possible, to remove from the chat rooms the comments where those suspicions were raised or I need to ask directly in the chat rooms for that?

Comment: If you were indeed referring to [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms/28332?noredirect=1#comment117384_28331), then please note that I didn't say that the comment was senseless. Please note the disjunction in the quoted statement.

Comment: @user170039 honestly your position is pretty unclear to me. So you have no problem with those comments after all? What's your point then?

Comment: @quid: You still haven't responded to my comment [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/how-to-deal-with-defamations-perpetrated-through-public-chat-rooms/28332?noredirect=1#comment117553_28332) (to both questions). Unless you do so, I can't rule out the possibility that (at least) I am talking past you.

Comment: @user170039 I meant the comments in OP *and* your comments but especially those in OP as regards being useful. Neither was senseless. The ones you quoted where only marginally useful to me personally.

Answer (score -1):

In this circumstance, if the mods have some circumstantial evidence that the user in question does not have sock puppet accounts, e.g.:

- different IP address
- online at different times
- other user uses different machine / browser / screen size etc.
- different writing style
- no common cookies
- whatever evidence is available to mods

then upon the allegation being made, and gimusi objecting to it, they really have a duty to gimusi to declare the existence of such evidence.  I don't think it would be right to declare what that evidence is, as to do so would arm sock-puppeteers with the knowledge to be more effective, but I don't think simply to say "there is no supporting evidence" is sufficient, if in actual fact "there is some limited circumstantial evidence to the contrary".

Comment: What you write makes (at  best) sense under the implicit assumption there is a or a few particular other accounts that we/somebody suspects to be sock-puppets. This is not necessarily the case even.

Comment: @quid I guess voting is anonymous then even to diamond mods.

Comment: That's a non sequitur. But indeed per site moderators cannot see the origin of a particular vote.

Comment: @quid It would seem to follow that if sock puppet accounts exist upvoting a particular user, then the ability to see the identity of up-voters would almost instantly lead to a collection of suspects to be eliminated from one's inquiries.